# Javascript/Jquery using class and Id to match specific Ids to one another in WordPress media upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

So what I am trying to do is have a function that runs through a list of id's and match them to one another. This button goes with this text box and this img. All I need is for the statement to match them to one another correctly by putting the Correct "Upload" button with the correct input box and corresponding img. I have never actually asked a question on this site in all the years I have used it because I have generally been able to find answers to even the most specific problems. I just wanted to thank you guys in the community for years of your help without even knowing it.

The php:

```
<input id="background_image_text_0" type="text" name="background_image_text_0" value="<?php echo get_option('background_image_0'); ?>" />
<input id="upload_button_0" type="button" class="upload_image_button button-primary" value="Insert Image" />
<img id="background_image_0" src="<?php echo get_option('background_image_0'); ?>" />

<input id="background_image_text_1" type="text" name="background_image_text_1" value="<?php echo get_option('background_image_1'); ?>" />
<input id="upload_button_1" type="button" class="upload_image_button button-primary" value="Insert Image" />
<img id="background_image_1" src="<?php echo get_option('background_image_1'); ?>" />
```

The Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  var mediaUploader;
  $('.upload_image_button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
      if (mediaUploader) {
      mediaUploader.open();
      return;
    }
    mediaUploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
      title: 'Choose Image',
      button: {
      text: 'Choose Image'
    }, multiple: false });

    mediaUploader.on('select', function() {
    var attachment = mediaUploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();

            var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.upload_image_button');
            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {

                alert(elements[i].name);

                if($(this).attr("name") == 'upload_button_' + i)
                {
                    image = document.getElementById('#background_image_' + i);
                    image.src = attachment.url;
                    $('#background_image_text_' + i).val(attachment.url);
                }
            //alert(elements[i].name);
            }
      // placeholder for original
      //$('#background_image_text_0').val(attachment.url);
    });
    mediaUploader.open();
  });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You state, "*All I need is for the statement to match them to one another correctly by putting the Correct "Upload" button with the correct input box and corresponding img.*" This is not clear and it's not clear what it is you are trying to accomplish. Are you trying to associate a specific button with a relative field? Are there more than 1? Please provide a better example.

Comment: I stated that is exactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: Hey @Twisty , I do apologize for my earlier comment (I assume it got deleted) it wasn't that I meant to be disrespectful but I sincerely didn't understand how you simultaneously didn't understand the question but replied with my exact questions.. It felt like you just wanted to demean someone who was, in earnest, trying to ask the question as clearly as they could. If you felt like I was being rude I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to the problem and I will give this to you now. If you have any revisions that would make the code more readable or suggestions that would help the code be more in line with proper standards PLEASE feel free to add them! I do ask that when commenting you provide a solution and not just criticism, it doesn't help anyone.

So the PHP code:

I have added a 'name' field to get post data and save within WordPress.

```
<input id="background_image_text_0" type="text" name="background_image_text_0" value="<?php echo get_option('background_image_0'); ?>" />
<input id="upload_button_0" type="button" class="upload_image_button button-primary" value="Insert Image" />
<img id="background_image_0" name="background_image_0" src="<?php echo get_option('background_image_0'); ?>" />

<input id="background_image_text_1" type="text" name="background_image_text_1" value="<?php echo get_option('background_image_1'); ?>" />
<input id="upload_button_1" type="button" class="upload_image_button button-primary" value="Insert Image" />
<img id="background_image_1" name="background_image_1" src="<?php echo get_option('background_image_1'); ?>" />

<input id="background_image_text_2" type="text" name="background_image_text_2" value="<?php echo get_option('background_image_2'); ?>" />
<input id="upload_button_2" type="button" class="upload_image_button button-primary" value="Insert Image" />
<img id="background_image_2" name="background_image_2" src="<?php echo get_option('background_image_2'); ?>" />
```

The JavaScript:

One of the reasons the original code did not work was because '**$(this).attr("name")**' passed 'undefined'. This was fixed by adding a var at the beginning to hold the 'name' but in this case I switched to getting the 'id'

As you can see I have added **var elem;** and **elem = $(this).attr('id');**

Here is the code to store the id:

```
  var elem;
  $('.upload_image_button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    elem = $(this).attr('id');
      if (mediaUploader) {
      mediaUploader.open();
      return;
    }
```

and here to use the stored ID:

```
if(elem == 'upload_button_' + i)
{
 var image = document.getElementById('background_image_' + i);
 image.src = attachment.url;
 $('#background_image_text_' + i).val(attachment.url);
}
```

The next problem was quite simple. **image = document.getElementById('#background_image_' + i);** there was no need for the '**#**'

The Fix:

```
 var image = document.getElementById('background_image_' + i);
```

The entire code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  var mediaUploader;
  //set variable 'elem' to pass $(this).attr('id') in a bit
  var elem;
  $('.upload_image_button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    elem = $(this).attr('id');
      if (mediaUploader) {
      mediaUploader.open();
      return;
    }
    mediaUploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
      title: 'Choose Image',
      button: {
      text: 'Choose Image'
    }, multiple: false });

    mediaUploader.on('select', function() {
    var attachment = mediaUploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();

            var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.upload_image_button');
            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {

                if(elem == 'upload_button_' + i)
                {

                    //this was set with '#background_image_' no need for '#'
                    var image = document.getElementById('background_image_' + i);
                    image.src = attachment.url;
                    $('#background_image_text_' + i).val(attachment.url);
                }

            }

    });
    mediaUploader.open();
  });
});
```

Thank you for taking the time to read this. If you have any edits or improvement suggestions, as I said, Please Let me know!